# Fragment views in TabLayout not yet created on activity create

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-tablayout

I keep running into a recurring issue in many of my apps and have been using all kinds of work arounds to "solve" it, but this time I've had it and I want to figure out a real solution.

I am trying to build a tabbed layout with two tabs where each tab shows some data which should be obtained from the internet. Once the data is obtained it is cached on the device so it can be restored instantly the next time the app is opened (and will then be refreshed in the background).

To this effect I am trying to load the cached data and display it in a RecyclerView in the first tab, and I want to do this on activity create. Before I do this I obviously set up all the tab layout stuff so that the tabs should be properly loaded. The problem is that they are not, it seems the Fragments that make up the tab pages don't have their views yet, hence I cannot access the RecyclerView on them.

Here is my Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends NetworkBusActivity
{
    // Views
    ViewPager tabPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    // Tab pager adapter
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    // Fragment one and two
    private MenuFragment menuFragment;
    private OrderFragment orderFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the views
        tabPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tabPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        // Setup the tab layouts
        this.setupTabs();

        // Show cached data
        this.setCachedItems();

        // Start loading new data in background
        this.startLoading();
    }

    private void setupTabs()
    {       
        // Create Fragments
        menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
        orderFragment = new OrderFragment();

        // Setup adapter
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(menuFragment, getString(R.string.title_menu));
        adapter.addFragment(orderFragment, getString(R.string.title_orders));
        tabPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Setup the tab layout
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(tabPager);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener()
        {
            // not shown
        });
    }    

    private void setCachedItems()
    {
        // Show cached data
        ArrayList<Item> items = Cache.menu.getItems();

        menuFragment.setItems(items);
    }

    private void startLoading()
    {
        // Start loading in background (not shown)
    }
}
```

It should be straightforward: create the views, create the fragments, and setup the tab layout, then load the cached data.

The `MenuFragment` extends a base class `ItemListFragment` which defines the `setItems` method:

```
public class MenuFragment extends ItemListFragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_menu, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected ItemListAdapter getAdapter(ArrayList<Item> items, boolean categorize)
    {
        return new MenuListAdapter(this, R.layout.row_item, items, categorize);
    }
}

public abstract class ItemListFragment extends Fragment
{
    private RecyclerView recycler;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recycler = (RecyclerView) view;
        recycler.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recycler.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<Item> items)
    {
        recycler.setAdapter(getAdapter(items, true));
    }

    protected abstract ItemListAdapter getAdapter(ArrayList<Item> items, boolean categorize);
}
```

Again straightforward: create the view in `onCreateView`, then obtain the RecyclerView in `onViewCreated`, and finally set the items with an adapter.

The problem is simple: the method `setCachedItems` in MainActivity is called **before** the `onCreateView` or `onViewCreated` methods are called in the Fragments. Hence, the `RecyclerView` is null and I can't set its adapter. Even though I am creating a new instance of the Fragments and adding them to a functional TabLayout before I call that method.

There seems to be some delay before the views are created, but I need to set the items already when the activity is created.

Where am I going wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In onViewCreated of fragment do this

((MainActivity)getActivity).setCachedData().....

Instead of on create of activity

Comment: See that's one of the work-arounds I was using. I don't like it one bit, it creates a dependency on the activity which I don't want and also it just seems like a hack. There must be some underlying thing I am not understanding and I'm looking to understand it so I can apply it to more scenarios which are similar. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: But what u r doing is wrong u trying to use recycler when it's not even created.

Comment: U can ovveride onResumedFragment() in activity and set cached data